# Simple Commerce - don't want to use PayPal

Tags: simple-commerce

I'd like a simple ecommerce solution, but don't want to use PayPal. I already have authorize.net set up, so I would rather use that option. Simple Commerce seems to be designed to work around PayPal. Is there a way to make it work with authorize.net? Are there alternative solutions to Simple Commerce that do not cost?

Comment: Could you provide an update to this, or mark one of the answers as accepted if it helped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any free alternatives for Authorize.net.

Charge (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge) is an affordable ($45) method to integrate Stripe.com and might be a good middle ground solution between Simple Commerce and a true eCommerce add-on such as CartThrob or Exp:resso Store.

Comment: +1 for Charge; the support has been outstanding, and it's fairly easy to work with.